# Log-normal model learning optimization

Tags: mixed-model, modeling, maximum-likelihood, lognormal-distribution

I am trying to model a variable (V) as a log normal distribution.
$$
V = \mu \cdot\eta\,, \  \text{where } \eta \text{ is log normal}
$$
Then 
$$
\ln V = ln(\mu) +\xi \\\\\text{where} \ \ \ \xi \   \text{ is }\ N(0,\sigma^2)
$$
V is a function of the binary inputs $x_i, i\in(1,...,n)$ . I want to make the model depend on the inputs by assuming that $\mu=\Pi{f_1(x_i)}$ and $\sigma=\Pi{f_2(x_i)}$ where $f_1(x_i)=c_i$ if $x_i=1$ or 1 if $x_i=0$ and $f_2(x_i)=d_i$ if $x_i=1$ or 1 when $x_i=0$. 
My aim to obtain the best estimates for the $c_i,d_i $ values given an set of $(V_i,\{x_j\}_{j\in(1,n)})$ measurements.
the log-likelihood in this case will become:
$$
-\log L = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\ln V - \Sigma \ln c_i}{\Pi{d_i}}\right)^2  + \log\sqrt{2\pi}\Pi{d_i}
$$

What will be the best way to tackle this problem, to solve and obtain the best values for the $c_i$ and $d_i$ parameters?
If I would assume that $\sigma$ is not a function of the inputs but rather a constant, I know I can solve the problem by a linear elastic-net regression, but when I take σ also as function of the inputs $x_i$ I am not sure which regression or method should I use to solve the problem? (how do I know the functional is convex?)

Comment: ok, I probably did a mistake in the exposition of the problem, what I assume is that when a variable is not in the sample, say $x_j$ then $d_j = 1$.

Comment: It looks like it's fine now. I think the additional term means it's no longer the case that increasing $d$s always makes the likelihood bigger. You may want to change 'minimizing' to 'maximizing', since you have logL now rather than (almost) -2logL.

Comment: You will want to fix your last paragraph, removing what's no longer relevant and adjusting it to only ask your present question.